# merge duplicate qs

Tags: support

the following was posted on SFSE and SO

Once one of them will be closed, they will be merged

admins: don't close them.

[Jquery Event handler fails to work after table is refreshed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9765/jquery-event-handler-fails-to-work-after-table-is-refreshed)

[Jquery event handler does not fire after Visualforce table refresh](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9734/jquery-event-handler-does-not-fire-after-visualforce-table-refresh)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Saariko.